# Set Product option default value:opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

How can i set product radio option's default value in opencart? 
Is there any way we can set the first option value to be default.

If not, then what will be the proper way to set in controller, view?

Comment: if you are satisfied please upvote and the green mark of my answer.

Comment: it's working or not? please update to me

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are Great

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will always help needed people. you can read my profile as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option selected by default for OpenCart 2.x**

You can seems as video as well:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18Amj0HwgSyQDg_THKBRcJciG7KEFvp_l/view?usp=sharing

**Download here Extension :**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q267HVk_IxfvGlDsTtj6OPtKjVcZPjyg

Better UX for your visitors! You can set up a default options for add to the cart from homepage or category.

**Steps for installing extension:**

1. Requiring installed vQmod because vQmod doesn't support installing via the composer itself.
2. run `update_structure.sql` file from SQL folder
3. optionally you can add your downloaded file with the path set (example: `/vqmod/xml/oc_default_option.xml`

Comment: I am not asking how to add radio button, I want like: Large option should be selected by default. how does this possible.

Comment: can you seem to this functionality as well.https://drive.google.com/file/d/18Amj0HwgSyQDg_THKBRcJciG7KEFvp_l/view?usp=sharing

if you are satisfied with it.after I will update here.

Comment: Yes thats awesome, Thanks a'lot. Can You please update, so i also mark it Green

Comment: but it's an extension. how I can send you. I will share drive link with you ??

Comment: I will update my answer with sharable link. just wait 5 minutes

Comment: Okay. It's really going to be very helpful.

Comment: hey @Mujahid Bhoraniya. how can i use this extension for opencart3.0.3 version?